# Serverless Offline & DynamoDB throws Local UnknownEndpoint: Inaccessible host: localhost at port 8000 Service may not be available in localhost region

Tags: typescript, serverless, serverless-framework, serverless-offline, amazon-dynamodb-local

I'm playin around with Serverless and I have no luck getting `serverless-offline` to work with `serverless-dynamodb-local`.
I have very minimal setup, it takes 3minutes to reproduce, I did it like this:

1. Generate a TS Serverless project like - `sls create -t aws-nodejs-typescript --path folder-name`
2. install dependencies `npm i`
3. Add DynamoDB local `npm install --save serverless-dynamodb-local`
4. Add serverless offline `npm install serverless-offline --save-dev`
5. Install dynamodb `sls dynamodb install`

Now I update `serverless.ts` file like

1. Include installed plugins in the correct order

```
  plugins: [
    'serverless-esbuild',
    'serverless-dynamodb-local',
    'serverless-offline'
  ],
```

2. In `custom` add DynamoDB config like

```
  custom: {
    esbuild: { ... },
    dynamodb: {
      stages: ['dev'],
      start: {
        migrate: true
      }
    }
```

3. Last step is to add DynamoDB in resources

```
  resources: {
    Resources: {
      usersTable: {
        Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table',
        Properties: {
          TableName: 'firstTable',
          AttributeDefinitions: [{
            AttributeName: 'id',
            AttributeType: 'S',
          }],
          KeySchema: [{
            AttributeName: 'id',
            KeyType: 'HASH'
          }],
          ProvisionedThroughput: {
            ReadCapacityUnits: 1,
            WriteCapacityUnits: 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**Now I try to spin it all up by running `sls offline start -s dev` and it throws error below (execution won't stop)
 (this error is logically not thrown if I remove `migrate: true` from `serverless.ts`)**

```
Dynamodb Local Started, Visit: http://localhost:8000/shell
UnknownEndpoint: Inaccessible host: `localhost' at port `8000'. This service may not be available in the `localhost' region.: DynamoDB - Error - 
Environment: darwin, node 17.3.1, framework 3.12.0 (local), plugin 6.2.1, SDK 4.3.2
Docs:        docs.serverless.com
Support:     forum.serverless.com
Bugs:        github.com/serverless/serverless/issues

Error:
UnknownEndpoint: Inaccessible host: `localhost' at port `8000'. This service may not be available in the `localhost' region.
at Request.ENOTFOUND_ERROR (...node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:529:46)
at Request.callListeners (...node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
at Request.emit (...node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
at Request.emit (...node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:686:14)
at error (...node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:361:22)
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (...node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/http/node.js:99:9)
at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:390:28)
at ClientRequest.emit (node:domain:475:12)
at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:442:9)
at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
at Socket.emit (node:domain:475:12)
at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:164:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:129:3)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

Even though error is thrown, I'm still able to successfully execute

```
> aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000 --region localhost
{
    "TableNames": []
}
```

I didn't change any other code than described above. I'd guess it will be something really basic, like I'm missing some config or something somewhere, but I can't find anything in docs or other posts that would help.
Any ideas welcome.

...and since I know some version had troubles in the past here is `package.json` I'm running with

```
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14.15.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@middy/core": "^2.5.3",
    "@middy/http-json-body-parser": "^2.5.3",
    "serverless-dynamodb-local": "^0.2.40"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@serverless/typescript": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.71",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.25",
    "esbuild": "^0.14.11",
    "json-schema-to-ts": "^1.5.0",
    "serverless": "^3.0.0",
    "serverless-esbuild": "^1.23.3",
    "serverless-offline": "^8.5.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.4.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3"
  },
```

**here's full `serverless.ts` if it helps**

```
const serverlessConfiguration: AWS = {
  service: 'aws-onboarding-api',
  frameworkVersion: '3',
  plugins: [
    'serverless-esbuild',
    'serverless-dynamodb-local',
    'serverless-offline'
  ],
  provider: {
    name: 'aws',
    runtime: 'nodejs14.x',
    apiGateway: {
      minimumCompressionSize: 1024,
      shouldStartNameWithService: true,
    },
    environment: {
      AWS_NODEJS_CONNECTION_REUSE_ENABLED: '1',
      NODE_OPTIONS: '--enable-source-maps --stack-trace-limit=1000',
    },
  },
  // import the function via paths
  functions: { hello },
  package: { individually: true },
  custom: {
      esbuild: {
      bundle: true,
      minify: false,
      sourcemap: true,
      exclude: ['aws-sdk'],
      target: 'node14',
      define: { 'require.resolve': undefined },
      platform: 'node',
      concurrency: 10,
    },
    dynamodb: {
      stages: ['dev'],
      start: {
        migrate: true
      }
    }
  },
  resources: {
    Resources: {
      usersTable: {
        Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table',
        Properties: {
          TableName: 'firstTable',
          AttributeDefinitions: [{
            AttributeName: 'id',
            AttributeType: 'S',
          }],
          KeySchema: [{
            AttributeName: 'id',
            KeyType: 'HASH'
          }],
          ProvisionedThroughput: {
            ReadCapacityUnits: 1,
            WriteCapacityUnits: 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So turned out it was a problem with my node version, I was running `v17.3.1`. After switching to `v16.4.0` it works like a charm.

From **@EdwinWong** comment: 
In node 18 in your serverless `custom.dynamodb.start.host` declare `127.0.0.1` and it should work
(I didn't test this)

Comment: THANK YOU FOR THIS! I was running node 18 and hitting the same wall you were. Downgrading to 16 did the trick.

Comment: I think downgrading should not be a valid solution, but just a workaround. A solution should identify the problem and provide a way to solve it in newer versions. In my case I'm using node 18 and the fetch API, so downgrading to v16 would be a step back in the development.

Comment: Hi @Pauli, I haven’t found any yet. I managed to get in working by using https in the connection string, but doesn’t seem to be a robust solution. Still working in it…

Comment: I knew it is working on node 16 but after I upgrade to node 18 I face the same issue. I found a way can be use in node 18 in your serverless `custom.dynamodb.start.host` declare `127.0.0.1`. That's it, and magic happened.

Comment: @EdwinWong thanks I'll add it to the answer as well

Comment: TYVM sir! Saved the day for node 18.